# Not fetching the last char of a string when needed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get some code to get the longest substring in alphabetical order of a given input string. Thing is, whenever i need to include the last char of the input string, my output is missing it. For instance, if i enter "abcde" i will get "abcd" as my output, although "e" should be there too.

I was thinking that i'm doing something blatantly wrong using "i" comparisons, but i just can't seem to find what that mistake is.

Any help and/or hints are highly appreciated.

```
s=input('Type in your string: ')

currentSubstring = ''
maxSubstring = ''

for i,c in enumerate(s):
    if(i+1 < len(s)):
        if(s[i] <= s[i+1]):
            currentSubstring = currentSubstring + s[i]
            if(len(currentSubstring) > len(maxSubstring)):
                maxSubstring = currentSubstring
        elif(s[i] > s[i+1]):
            if(currentSubstring != ''):
                currentSubstring = currentSubstring + s[i]
                if(len(currentSubstring) > len(maxSubstring)):
                    maxSubstring = currentSubstring
            currentSubstring = ''

print(maxSubstring)
```

Comment: Suggestion - Running this code in Pycharm using its debugger might help. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You have an `if(i+1 < len(s)):` that's true for everything but the last character, and you don't have an `else:`, so you aren't running anything at all on the last character. Meanwhile, inside the `if` part, you add `s[i]`, not `s[i+1]`, so that's also not going to add the last character. So there's no way the last character can ever get added.

Comment: @abamert I am using the if(i+1 < len(s)): because if i don't i am getting an error when running the programme since it gets out of the string length

Comment: One thing to consider: You want to handle the last character the same as a non-last character that's smaller than the next character, right? Meanwhile, you don't really need that `elif` condition, because it'll always be true, so you can just use `else:`. So, what could you do with `if i+1 == len(s) or s[i] <= s[i+1]:` here? (Notice that `or` is short-circuiting: if `i+1 == len(s)` is true, the whole thing is true, and it will never check `s[i] <= s[i+1]` and raise that `IndexError`.)

Comment: @abament Thanks, that was helpful. I noticed another problem. If i have as a reversed one, e.g. "edcba" i would expect to get "e" as a result. However, i get "a". Do i need to iterate my substring somewhere or have another len() check?

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it, the if(currentSubstring != ''): was ruining this part i was talking about on the last comment.

Thank you once again